# DYMO Label cut-off print on Windows 8.1 and Windows 10

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-10, dymo

We have encountered a cut-off print issue with DYMO LabelWriter 450 Turbo after we have upgraded to Windows 10. After some investigation we found out that the same issue can occur on some of Windows 8.1 machines as well. We use DYMO.Label.Framework in our program.

We have the following investigation results for now:

1. Labels are printed correct via DYMO App v8.5.1.1816
2. Labels with long barcodes or long lines are cut-off, there’s just a half of them is printed
3. It works if we build the app with .NET framework 3.5
4. It doesn’t work if we build the app with .NET framework 4.0-4.6

We found some related questions like https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/4370e2c1-21ad-4b65-a505-8c7696f909b9/dymo-label-barcode-cutoff-on-windows-81?forum=w8itproappcompat or http://developers.dymo.com/2014/01/02/windows-8-1-barcodes/#comment-82838 but no solution has been found yet.

Guys from DYMO confirmed that there is a bug in the .NET Framework that effects the way Microsoft handles printers with “non-square” resolutions (ex.600×300). When graphics are drawn on a label, DYMO prints at this higher resolution instead of the normal 300×300 to help with barcode quality/scanning. They had logged the issue with Microsoft and Microsoft claim to have fixed the problem in .NET 4.6, but we tried it, and it didn't work. DYMO guys are continuing to look into this issue and trying to find workarounds.

Workaround:
As a temporary solution, we've built .NET Framework 3.5 app that prints labels with DYMO.Label.Framework and we use this exe from our main app.

Comment: Experiencing the exact same problem (Windows 10). Thanks for the 3.5 suggestion. Please post when you've found a permanent solution.

Comment: For further support on this matter I would like to refer you to our developers forum http://developers.dymo.com/ You may also contact our software developers directly from there. I hope to have been of service to you via this message. If you have further questions please contact us via www.dymo.com and your country or language if choice. Kind regards, Paul
Dymo customer service

Comment: +1, I am having the same issue. The developers.dymo.com site has not been helpful. Hopefully the solution can be posted soon.

Answer (score 1):

I got my barcodes to print correctly on Windows 10 by redesigning my label with a portrait orientation.

See information here: http://developers.dymo.com/2015/09/30/barcode-printing-issues/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and found the solution was to install this file DLS8Setup.8.7.2.exe 166,417Kb  on all the affected machines, and it worked flawlessly after that. I'm not sure what Dymo has been doing with its drivers as of late, but they are getting worse.

http://download.dymo.com/dymo/Software/Win/DLS8Setup.8.7.2.exe

Comment: I sent my dymo printer back, it had too many driver issues.  I went with a Honeywell, it was soo much more reliable when installing it on different PCs